# get current post id inside hook

Tags: posts

I have created this hook to send notification only when new post is published.
In notification I am sending link and title of post which is newly created. For that, I need current post id inside function. How can I get it ?

```
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'send_notification', 1 );
function send_notification(){

        $post_data['ID'] = the_ID();

        $post_id =  $post_data['ID'];
        global $wpdb;

        $sel2 = mysql_query("select * from gcm_users");
        while($data1  = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel2)) 
        {

            $key = $data1['gcm_regid'];
            include_once '../blogdroid/config.php';
            include_once '../blogdroid/GCM.php';

            $gcm = new GCM();
            $sel = mysql_query("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."posts where ID='$post_id'");
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel);
            $Pname = $data['post_title'];
            $registatoin_ids = array($key);
            if($Pname != 'Auto Draft')
            {
                    $message = array("blog" => 'New Blog Arrived '.$Pname );

                    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids,$message);
            }

        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new_to_publish` hook has one argument: `$post`.  Use that to get the post id.  Here is your editted code:

```
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'send_notification', 1, 1 );
function send_notification( $post ){    
        $post_id =  $post->ID;;
        global $wpdb;

        $sel2 = mysql_query("select * from gcm_users");
        while($data1  = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel2)) 
        {

            $key = $data1['gcm_regid'];
            include_once '../blogdroid/config.php';
            include_once '../blogdroid/GCM.php';

            $gcm = new GCM();
            $sel = mysql_query("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."posts where ID='$post_id'");
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel);
            $Pname = $data['post_title'];
            $registatoin_ids = array($key);
            if($Pname != 'Auto Draft')
            {
                    $message = array("blog" => 'New Blog Arrived '.$Pname );

                    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids,$message);
            }

        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually i needed draft_to_publish, to run this function only on new post.

Comment: that should work the same way.